# Design ImageView with curved edges Android

Tags: android

[image of the modal design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACsc5.png)This is the design I want to achieve in android, where the center one is image and the edges are rounded corners, when scrolled up it should scroll till the last

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using an `imageView` and a `shape` as `background`.

Also, you could use this library: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView